# Get msoluser by a certain license

Tags: powershell, office365

I am trying to get users in office 365 by get-msoluser by a certain license. For some reason I cannot get it to work in the sense that The $user is returning nothing. I am also posistive that it is the correct license as well. Any ideas on what going wrong.

```
$c = Get-Credential
Connect-MsolService -Credential $c
$accountsku = Get-MsolAccountSku
$userMSOL = Get-MsolUser -All | Where {$_.Licenses.AccountSku -eq $accountsku[0].AccountSkuId}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Licenses` is a *collection* property (contain multiple values), so you need to replace the expression:

```
Where {$_.Licenses.AccountSku -eq $accountsku[0].AccountSkuId}
```

with

```
Where { $_.Licenses.accountskuid -contains $accountsku[0].AccountSkuId }
```

**Example**

```
$c = Get-Credential
Connect-MsolService -Credential $c
$accountsku = Get-MsolAccountSku
$userMSOL = Get-MsolUser -All | where { $_.Licenses.accountskuid -contains $accountsku[0].AccountSkuId }
```

Comment: little stuff can make a big difference!